# Do you always need to clock out the old pixels when reading from a camera?

Tags: arduino, sensor, adc, camera, delay

I'm writing a program to work with a TSL1401R-LF Linescan Module. It works by reading in a 1 X 128 array of pixels. I've gotten the camera to work properly and my `readPixels()` method is able to read in the pixels accurately.

However, I'm forced to run a `timming()` method prior to my `readPixels()` method or else the program fails. The `timming()` pretty much does exactly the same thing as the `readPixels()` method except it doesn't store the outputted values. When I comment it out and only use `readPixels()` my image becomes saturated and I only get values of 1023 even when a dark object is in the way of the cameras.

This might make more sense when looking at the actual code:

```
void timming()
{

  digitalWriteFast(SI, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(SI, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  for(int i = 0; i < 129; i++)
  {
    digitalWriteFast(CLK, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
    digitalWriteFast(CLK, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
  }

}

void readPixels()  
{
  digitalWriteFast(SI, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(SI, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWriteFast(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
  { 
    digitalWriteFast(CLK, HIGH);
    pixelsArray1[i]=analogRead(Cam1Aout);
    pixelsArray2[i]=analogRead(Cam2Aout);
    pixelsArray3[i]=analogRead(Cam3Aout);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
    digitalWriteFast(CLK, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
  }

  digitalWriteFast(CLK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
  digitalWriteFast(CLK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);

  delayMicroseconds(20);
}
```

TL;DR

Basically what I'm asking if there is a way to get my program to work without having to use the `timming()` method.

Datasheet: http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf/58/61/586128/tsl1401r-lf.pdf

Comment: Add the datasheet link again. There are other ways : some cameras have a shutter pulse; lengthen or shorten it according to light condition, to avoid saturating your pixels. But I don't know if your sensor does.

Comment: I've added it, the explanation on integration time is on pages 8 and 9. That's where I was told to do the clocking of n+1 pixels on startup.

Comment: As far as I can see, it's not about clocking out the old pixels but controlling the integration time. The "simple" interface comes at a cost : you have to jump through hoops to control the whole thing through only 2 pins. There are better ways than loop/digitalWrite but they would normally involve special purpose hardware or an FPGA. If you're stuck with an Arduino you can still control the integration time by adjusting delayTime separately for the first 18 cycles (reset) and remainder(integration). Or clock them as fast as you can, then wait an appropriate time before the next frame.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's what I thought at first too, but reducing the integration time is supposed to make the pixels darker since the sensor has less time to charge. I know this because as I made `delayTime` smaller I got lower and lower values. So if the `timming()` method is just their to increase the integration time then I shouldn't be getting saturated value. Right? Sorry if I'm not getting it, this is my first timer working with a camera.

Comment: The timing() method is there to DECREASE the integration time. Else the pixels have been integrating and integrating and integrating and integrating and integrating for however long since the last time you did a readPixels().

Comment: I have no idea how slow 384 AnalogReads are on an Arduino but I'm guessing ... slow. So the timing method(`timming()`) is presumably much faster, and gives a much shorter integration time (no saturation) than the previous `readPixels()` function.

Comment: @RichardCrowley how can that be the case if the integration time only starts after the first 18 clock cycles?

Comment: @BrianDrummond My analogRead is optimized and doesn't take that long at all.

Comment: The actual behavior of the chip appears to disagree with the "starts after the first 18 clock cycles" theory.  Or perhaps "starts after" means something different than what we think it does.

Comment: @RichardCrowley can you expand on what you mean? The datasheet states that the integration time is from the 19th CLK pulse to the next SI pulse.

Comment: Where did this timing() and readPixels() code come from? Perhaps you should consult (or at least cite) this source to reveal the rest of the picture. I see no mention of a timing() method in the data sheet.

Comment: @RichardCrowley If you go to page 9 in the datasheet and read the first paragraph you will see that it is good practice to run the clock (n+1) times after the first SI pulse.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the answer is quite simple: run readPixels() twice in quick succession. As it stands, if you don't run timing(), when you run readPixels() the 1401 has been sitting there integrating for some unknown (but very long) time, so of course your pixel values are saturated. So timing() resets the pixel integrators to zero, and then readPixels() can properly acquire data. However, running readPixels() the first time will have the same effect.

Of course, when you do this you'll need to disregard the first set of values produced by readPixels(), since they will be a uniform 1023.

So the answer to your title question is - of course.

Comment: But isn't their a way to stop the integration time at the end of the `readPixels()` so that the values don't become saturated? Also do you know what the datasheet is talking about when it says that the integration time ends at the HOLD positive pulse.

Comment: No. Integration is halted for the 18 clock cycles following the receipt of an SI pulse. That's it. The rest of the time the integrators are integrating. It's up to the user (you) to control the integration time. If the pixels are saturating, reduce illumination. If you won't do that, simply ignore the results of the first readPixels(). This is not a high-class, flexible camera. It has a minimal interface, so you get a very limited range of operational modes (that is, one). On the data sheet, "Hold" is also called "System Reset" on Figure 10.

Comment: Couldn't you just send an impulse to the SI at the end of the `readPixels()` method?

Comment: Well, maybe. The data sheet is not forthcoming. But what do you have against a dummy read cycle, anyways?

Comment: It's basically doubling the total runtime of my program. I'm trying to make it fast so that I can get a high frame rate.

Comment: But you only need to run the dummy read once, when you start the program. After that, you just keep running readPixel(). So  your sequence will be, readPixel()(dummy), readPixel()(use data), readPixel()(use data), etc. At startup, the sensor has been sitting there integrating for a long time. But once you start running, integration time is just the delay between frames. So the very first read is garbage, but after that you should have no problems.